# In vivo et in vitro

Tags: usage, latin, locutions

Les locutions adverbiales d'origine lative *in vitro* et *in vivo* sont-elles courantes ou non ? Par exemple :

> Les mêmes forces agissent in vivo sur les cellules mais les forces sont illustrées in vitro.

Dans la phrase ci-dessus, est-il préférable de rendre par une périphrase le sens de celles-ci ?

**EDIT**

Extrait d'origine anglais :

> The same forces acted on the cells in vivo, but the forces are
>   illustrated (i.e. in a Figure) in vitro because it is an easier
>   situation to visualise and to draw.

Traduction corrigée par @jlliagre (voir commentaires) :

> Les mêmes forces agissent sur les cellules in vivo mais elles sont
>   illustrées ici in vitro.

Comment: Courant**e**s... dans le milieu scientifique de la bio oui assurément! (et sans équivalent). Et aussi dans les ouvrages de vulgarisation. Périphraser ? Même Jules Verne ne le fait pas! ;)

Comment: Que veux-tu dire par ***les forces sont illustrées** in vitro* ? Cette expression n'a pour moi pas de sens; cf. les différents sens d'[illustrer](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/illustrer) du TLFi

Comment: @jlliagre In fact I want to translate the follow sentence: The same forces acted on the cells in vivo, but the forces are illustrated (i.e. in a Figure) in vitro because it is an easier situation to visualise and to draw.

Comment: Got it. I would then suggest **Les mêmes forces agissent sur les cellules *in vivo* mais elles sont illustrées ici *in vitro*.**

Comment: @jlliagre Parfait:-)! Merci beaucoup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En complément à une réponse dans les commentaires on peut dire que ces expressions sont aussi utilisées couramment par les journalistes scientifiques et que toute personne dont l'éducation a permis une familiarité avec celles-ci peut les utiliser si nécessaire; elles ne sont pas limitées à un usage scientifique.

En ce qui concerne leur remplacement par des périphrases, je ne pense pas que l'on doive être aussi catégorique que @aCoswt; disons qu'à l'ordinaire, en particulier dans la routine des communications professionnelles, il n'y a aucune hésitation à avoir et les périphrases n'apportent vraiment pas beaucoup; cependant rien n'empêche, par exemple, dans  les conversations moins formelles, de dire « Les mêmes forces agissent sur les cellules dans un organisme mais elles sont illustrées dans l'éprouvette. »