# Un synonyme de l'expression "Dans la vraie vie"

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

J'effectue en ce moment une analyse de data science et l'objectif de cette dernière est de tester les résultats obtenus de manière théorique "dans la vraie vie". (Exemple : je réalise une étude sur les pneus et j'ai des résultats théoriques. J'aimerai observer ces résultats sur de vrais pneus pour voir si mon modèle fonctionne).

Cependant, je dois écrire un rapport et utiliser l'expression "dans la vraie vie" ne me semble pas approprié. Il y a bien "expérimentalement" qui correspondrait à peu près à ce que je souhaite, mais je ne réalise pas d'expérience pour tester mon modèle et je fais plutôt des observations "dans la vraie vie".

En somme, j'aimerais écrire cette phrase : "Les résultats théoriques de cette étude sont positifs. Il est donc temps d'éprouver ces résultats [?]" et remplacer le [?] par un mot ou une expression désignant ce que je recherche.

Comment: Have a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_vivo (see also the related vocabulary).

Comment: Merci pour le lien. In vivo ne semble pas correspondre à mon problème étant donné qu'il ne convient qu'à ce qui touche au vivant. Par contre, en regardant le vocabulaire relié, l'expression in situ semble correspondre à ce que je souhaite. Cependant, cela ne me semble pas une expression très utilisée, celle-ci sera-t-elle comprise par une majorité de personnes ? (Je ne connaissais pas cette expression auparavant)

Comment: In situ sera parfaitement compris par des personnes bien éduquées. Par exemple dans mon domaine (mécanique) on parle de la caractérisation in-situ. Ces expressions d'origine latine sont assez répandues.

Comment: Je ne suis pas locuteur natif et pour cette raison j'évite de donner une réponse. D'après mon expérience (projets académiques -écoles d'ingénieurs, universités- en parténariat avec l'industrie) les expressions in situ, in vivo, etc. seront comprises. Même par des personnes qui n'ont pas étudié le latin au secondaire. Vous n'avez pas précisé à qui ce rapport s'adresse. Si c'est un rapport de stage par exemple, je crois que in situ sera comprise et de plus je la trouve une expression plutôt séduisant:-)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J'utiliserais la locution d'origine latine *in situ*. Dans mon domaine (mécanique)-mais je crois dans d'autres domaines aussi- cette locution serait parfaitement comprise même par des personnes n'ayant pas étudié le latin au sécondaire.

Par exemple voici quelques résultats pertinents tirés par un vite googling :

http://mateis.insa-lyon.fr/fr/content/caracterisation-microstructurale-situ-etou-3d

https://tel.archives-ouvertes.fr/tel-01005656/

https://www.cstb.fr/assets/documents/cstb-caracterisation-insitu-bancs-essais-aev-appareils-mesure-fenetres.pdf

https://www.axelera.org/retour-evenements/caracterisation-in-situ-des-sols-pollues/

Bien sûr mon expérience est plutôt académique (école d'ingénieurs, universités) mais même les partenaires industriels l'emploient aussi.

Dans tous les cas, vous pouvez donner la définition lors du premier emploi de la locution dans votre rapport et après l'utiliser librement. C'est une pratique bien répandue.

Aditionellement les locutions latines (et grecques également:-)!) sont séduisantes. Nous pourrions aussi faire preuve de notre culture.

Voir aussi la question :

[In vivo et in vitro](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/31932/in-vivo-et-in-vitro)

Comme @LPH y remarque :

"...(O)n peut dire que ces expressions sont aussi utilisées couramment par les journalistes scientifiques et que toute personne dont l'éducation a permis une familiarité avec celles-ci peut les utiliser si nécessaire; elles ne sont pas limitées à un usage scientifique."

Comment: C'est une locution qui semblerait convenir d'après le TLFi : IN SITU, loc. adv.
Dans son cadre naturel, à sa place normale, habituelle. Découvrir des diamants in situ, dans la roche même où ils s'étaient formés (Lar. 19e Suppl. 1890-Lar. encyclop.). D'après [l'enc. libre](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_situ) cependant, cela n'est pas aussi certain (arts, biologie, géologie, environnement). D'après [l'internaute](https://www.linternaute.fr/dictionnaire/fr/definition/in-situ/) l'emploi serait plus général (sens 3) et « in situ » pourrait être un choix idéal.

Answer (score 5):

Effectivement, c'est une bonne idée de conserver les guillemets autour de cette expression (dans la vrai vie), elle n'est pas identifiable à quelque chose de bien spécifique pour l'instant.

Une expression consacrée qui correspond à ce que vous cherchez et qui est applicable dans   de nombreux domaines est « **sur le terrain** ».

Comment: Il est vrai que j'avais pas pensé à "sur le terrain " et il peut tout à fait convenir. Cependant, je trouve que cette expression n'est peut-être pas assez soutenue pour un rapport, je me trompe peut-être.

Comment: @OTDM En effet, une locution comme « in situ » est plus formelle et semblerait convenir ; il faudrait s'assurer de cela.

Answer (score 5):

"Les résultats théoriques de cette étude sont positifs. Il est donc temps d'éprouver ces résultats **à l'échelle de la réalité.**"

"Les résultats théoriques de cette étude sont positifs. Il est donc temps d'éprouver ces résultats **dans le monde réel.**"

"Les résultats théoriques de cette étude sont positifs. Il est donc temps d'éprouver ces résultats **dans un contexte concret/réel/pratique.**"

Answer (score 5):

Une suggestion en plus des autres: "il est temps d'éprouver ces résultats *en conditions réelles*.

Answer (score 3):

D'où je viens (Français Canadien), nous comparons souvent la théorie et la pratique. Nous exerçons la théorie à travers la pratique. Alors, je serais tenté d'écrire :

> Les résultats théoriques de cette étude sont positifs. Il est donc temps d'éprouver ces résultats dans un environnement pratique.